# Rspec test for signed_in and admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I have controlled access to certain nav buttons through my _header partial to be found in app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb with:

```
<% if signed_in? && current_user.admin? %>
  <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
  etc
```

now I would like to write a test for a user to be signed in and also that the admin? boolean is true. I do have Factories setup such that we have:

```
factory :admin do
  admin true
end
```

and the test I have so far is:

```
describe "as an admin user" do
  let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
  before do
    sign_in admin
    visit root_path

    *this is where I want to test that the Profile, Settings, Users and New User
     nav buttons are accessible but I am not sure what the test should say?*
    *also should I add:
     let (:signed_in) {FactoryGirl.create(user) } in under the first 'let'?*
```

The reason I wonder about whether I need the second 'let' is because I need to test that the user is signed_in and that they have admin privileges.

***Update***
I revised the test somewhat, visit users_path instead of root_path and then I added the following:

```
    it { should have_link('Users', href: users_path) }
    it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_link('New User', href: new_user_path) }

    it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }

    it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
  end
end
```

The tests pass except for the 'Profile', 'New User', and 'Settings' links.

If you visit the actual 'New User' page you can see all the Links and click on them and they all work.

Any ideas or suggestions.

***Update 1***
If I create a new file with just this test in it and I def a method "valid_signin(admin)" and then wherever I have user_path(user) I replace it with user_path(admin) and lastly in the before do block I delete the existing two lines and replace with the valid_signin(admin) ... then I get the test to pass. 
The thing that confused me was that I had an existing valid_signin(employee) and I thought I could just use valid_signin(admin).
Well now I have to get the test to pass in context.